# Passing multiple different Mongodb queries to EJS?

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs

When a user submits a form on my site, I want to show them three items: a breakfast item, a lunch item, and a dinner item. To do this, I thought I'd have to individually do a db.collection("recipes").findOne, then return the result of that code to a variable I could then pass to EJS using res.render("meal-plan", {breakfast:breakfast});

However, it turns out the variables gathered from the findOne query must be passed to EJS before the findOne query is closed or else you can't access them. Now I'm stuck with something like this:

```
var breakfast;    
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', function (err, client) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var db = client.db('food_app');

            db.collection("recipes").findOne({ "breakfast" : true}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(result.title);
                    breakfast = result;
                    client.close();
                }
            res.render("meal-plan.ejs", {breakfast:breakfast}); 
            });
        });
```

This successfully allows me to pass the breakfast variable to EJS. However, I want to have multiple variables to pass (breakfast, lunch, dinner). How can I do this if I can only pass one variable? Is it acceptable to use multiple res.renders in multiple queries so I can copy/paste the MongoClient code three times or put it in a function?

Answer (score 0):

In meal-plan.ejs, you should use forEach
See more at https://ejs.co

```
<%breakfast.forEach(bf){%>
    <p><%bf.name%></p>
<%}%>
```